# Configure jenkins job: rm command not found

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to configure a jenkins job and i added the following lines to shell text area:

```
PATH="/home/${USER}/reportLogsComparator/";
RESULT_FILE="target/result.txt";

#remove previous results
cd ${PATH}
rm -f ${RESULT_FILE}
```

but the result is:

```
+ PATH=/home/build/reportLogsComparator/
+ RESULT_FILE=target/result.txt
+ cd /home/build/reportLogsComparator/
+ rm -f target/result.txt
/tmp/hudson6849808815020420288.sh: line 7: rm: command not found
```

Also, I tried with

`rm -f "$RESULT_FILE"`

and with the path hardcoded, but with no success.

Comment: You are blowing up the `PATH` variable with your assignment. You are breaking the shell. Don't use `ALL_CAPS` variables in scripts as they are "reserved" for the shell use.

Answer (score 2):

```
PATH="/home/${USER}/reportLogsComparator/"
```

should probably be

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/${USER}/reportLogsComparator"
```

This way, you're appending that directory to your current path instead of replacing $PATH entirely.